# Using jQueryFileUpload library with require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jquery-file-upload

I am using [this file upload library](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with require.js. When I try to run it I get a 404 not found error

> localhost/js/jam/tmpl.js 404 (Not Found)

It seems like its looking for this "tmpl.js" file which I can't find anywhere. There is a reference to this file on line 21 of the "jquery.fileupload-ui.js" file that comes with the fileupload package.

```
(function (factory) {
'use strict';
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
    define([
        'jquery',
        'tmpl',
        'load-image',
        './jquery.fileupload-fp'
    ], factory);
```

Again I'm not sure where this this is located or where its coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need download file tmpl.js (or tmpl.min.js) from https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates
It's Blueimp's own template engine.

Full list of plugin requirements with links: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#requirements